# Keycloak : How to extend the admin REST API

Tags: rest, keycloak, admin

I have extended the Keycloak REST API to add my REST endpoint to the URL `{{server}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/myApi` using mechanisms described in the Keycloak documentation and it works fine.

However, my api is an internal company one and my IT asked me to put it behind the /admin (for legitimate security reasons) and thus I should have my api here : `{{server}}/auth/admin/realms/{{realm}}/myApi`

Is it possible to add endpoints "behind" to the /admin ?

I currently use the (outdated) version 15.0.2 of Keycloak with WildFly

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's very much possible and it's very simple too, as you said you already extended the API without `"/admin"` in your path so my guess you extended with **RealmResourceProvider**, To extend API with `"/admin"` path in your api, Just extend **AdminRealmResourceProvider** class instead of **RealmResourceProvider**, same for respective provider factory class

**NOTE**: The **AdminRealmResourceProvider** interface also gives you the adminEvent and Auth by default, Now your API expect with bearer token by default since it's now a Admin API, Hope the information helpful to you...

Importantly this **AdminRealmResourceProvider** class, or say this functionality of extending admin apis only exists in >= Keycloak version 19

Answer (score 1):

You can extend **/admin** endpoint with custom path by using **AdminRealmResourceProvider, AdminRealmResourceProviderFactory** classes as below.

```
public class CustomAdminRealmResourceProvider implements AdminRealmResourceProvider, AdminRealmResourceProviderFactory {
  
  @Override
  public AdminRealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
    return this;
  }
  
  @Override
  public Object getResource(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, AdminPermissionEvaluator auth, AdminEventBuilder adminEvent) {
    return new CustomMyApiResource(session, auth);
  }

  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return "myApi";
  }
  
  @Override
  public void init(Scope config) {  }

  @Override
  public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {}

  @Override
  public void close() {}
}
```

Comment: See this [article](https://read.zyntaxmind.com/how-to-extend-keycloak-with-custom-entities-293c1b7e08bc) for more details.